# Deleting Objects from any entities in WCF Data Service gives me an exception

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf data service that has multiple entities. I have a problem with deleting objects from any entity as I get this exception. My service is hosted as a cloud service in Azure.

**It gives me this error message "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."**

**By the way it works well while running the WCF Data service on local host.** `

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Services.Client.SaveResult.HandleResponse()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseSaveResult.EndRequest()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()
       at testODataClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Learn\My Projects\Visual Studio Projects\testODataClient\testODataClient\Program.cs:line 238
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

       StatusCode=401
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem which is to set UsePostingTunneling to true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.useposttunneling.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce63fde6-5547-447d-8d4d-e3699701d3e8/how-to-configure-iis-75-to-allow-inserts-and-deletes-with-wcf-data-services-put-and-delete?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Answer (score 0):

Add following element into web.config might be another solution

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/514f2e2d-54a8-4516-976d-94a879209173/http-delete-request-to-svc-returns-4013-unauthorized?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting